# Why does jenkins need sudo password when ssh account doesn't?

Tags: linux, jenkins, sudo

My linux user account has the rights to run a particular sudo command without a password prompt. I am trying to implements jenkins to run this command. It is set up to ssh as my user account on the box with the Publish Over SSH plugin.

When I am in the box $USER shows the correct user, but when I try to run "sudo {command}" (which runs without password when I am using that box normally with my user) it requires password. What is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is configured to do so. There is file `/etc/sudoers` specifying these rules and there is respective manual page describing how does this file and the roles work. It is probably a good start to read.